# Automatically clean Windows recycle bin files & folders if they originated from a certain directory

Tags: windows, windows-11, onedrive, recycle-bin

How to automatically clean Windows recycle bin files & folders if they originated from a certain directory?

Context: I'm syncing with an App from my mobile phone to OneDrive. If the file gets deleted from my phone I also want it to remove it from OneDrive. However, my PC (the OneDrive target so to say), puts all those deleted files into the recycle bin instead of deleting them forever. Now I want to have a rule that automatically removes recycle bin items if they originated from the `%OneDriveLocation%\MySync` folder (or prevent items going into the recycle bin if they come from this folder would be also okay).

Comment: You mean that you delete a OneDrive file via the phone, then find it in the PC's Recycle Bin?

Comment: No, I delete a file on my phone, a mirror-all-files-on-my-phone-to-a-onedrive-location deletes it from OneDrive and my PC OneDrive moves the file to the PC's recycle bin.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test the following idea, as I'm not using OneDrive,
but here it is for Windows.

**Step 1** : [Map OneDrive to a Drive Letter](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/map-onedrive-to-a-drive-letter-windows-11.htm)

- In a web browser visit OneDrive and sign-in
- From the URL, copy your CID number found after "cid="
- In Explorer, right-click "This PC" and select "Map network drive"
- In the mapping dialog, enter `https://d.docs.live.net/CID-number`,
  select a drive letter from the drop-down list
  and click Finish
- Enter your OneDrive credentials and check "Remember my credentials",
  then click OK
- You may Rename your OneDrive in Explorer.

**Step 2** : Exclude the mapped drive from the Recycle Bin

- Right-click the Recycle Bin icon on the desktop and select Properties
- Click the mapped drive
- Click "Don't move files to the Recycle Bin.
  Remove files immediately when deleted."
- Click OK.

This should work if OneDrive deletes the files on Windows by
using API calls that respect the Properties of the Recycle Bin.

Comment: Thanks, very nice idea. However, I want only one sub directory of OneDrive to be excluded. Maybe I can mount the sub directory though...need to test this out.